# EventHandler that changes another widget/control's properties

Tags: c#, event-handling, overloading, gtk#

I'm having trouble with event handling. I'm using gtk# to create a form app, with two labels and a set of buttons between them.

```
    Label Character1 = new Label ("Character1");
    Label Character2 = new Label ("Character2");
    HBox layoutTBS = new HBox(true,50);
    layoutTBS.PackStart (Character1, false,true,3);

    Button melee = new Button ("Melee");
    Button range = new Button ("Ranged");
    Button magic = new Button ("Magic");
    melee.ButtonPressEvent += ButtonPressEventHandler;
```

---

This is the supposed custom 'event handler'

```
private static void ButtonPresseventHandler (object obj, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
{
        if (args.Event.Type == Gdk.EventType.TwoButtonPress) {

            Character1.Text = "Character1 does a melee attack";
        }
}
```

I am trying to make the activation of the 'button press' event to change the text of a label.
The label 'Character1' cannot have its Text property changed because it was not passed to the event handler. Am I correct to say that I must overload the default 'button press event handler' of the button class to have another control as an argument? If so, how do I do that? 
If not so, how might I go about to make it so that the event of one control being activated will change the property of another control.

Cheers

Comment: Is the `ButtonPressed` method in the same class as your `Character1` textbox?

Comment: No, The `ButtonPressed` method belongs to the `button` class. I want it to change the `Text` property of the `Character1` textbox.
(Forgive me if I misunderstood the question, I'm not yet too acquainted with OOP terminology)

Comment: That is not what i ment. In what class did you define `Button melee = new Button ("Melee");`

Comment: Oh I see, yes they are in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the `Label` at the class level. That way, when you're inside the Button `Click` method, you can access it.

For example, i will assume all code is inside your `Form` class:

```
public class Form
{
    public Button Mele { get; set; }
    public Label Character1 { get; set; }

    public Form()
    {
         Character1 = new TextBox();
         Mele = new Button();
         Mele.Click += OnButtonClicked;
    }

 private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
      // Since Character1 is declared at class level, you may
      // access it now inside the method
     Character1.Text = "Mele has been clicked!";
}
```

Comment: Thnx Yuval, you were right, I had to declare it on the class level. But not I've ran into another problem.
When I declare the `Button` and `Labels` on the class level, they suddenly become `Fields` instead of `Variable`. The program does not work, I'm wondering if this may be the problem.

Comment: I think you should create a new question for your other problem. If this answered helped you, please mark it as an answer by clicking the empty checkmark under the vote count.